# Reflection GetValue of static field with circular dependency returns null

Tags: c#, reflection, visual-studio-2015, static, c#-6.0

*Note: The following code actually works okay, but shows the scenario that is failing in my own solution. See the bottom of this post for more information.*

With these classes:

```
public class MainType {
   public static readonly MainType One = new MainType();
   public static readonly MainType Two = SubType.Two;
}

public sealed class SubType : MainType {
   public new static readonly SubType Two = new SubType();
}
```

Get fields `One` and `Two`:

```
List<FieldInfo> fieldInfos = typeof(MainType)
   .GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
   .Where(f => typeof(MainType).IsAssignableFrom(f.FieldType))
   .ToList();
```

Finally, get their values:

```
List<MainType> publicMainTypes = fieldInfos
   .Select(f => (MainType) f.GetValue(null))
   .ToList();
```

In LinqPad or in a simple unit test class with the above code, everything works okay. But in my solution, where I have some unit tests that want to work with all instances of these fields, `GetValue` works fine to return fields of the parent type, but where the parent fields are supposed have instances of the subtype, they always instead give `null`! (If that happened here, the final list would be `{ One, null }` instead of `{ One, Two }`.)  The test class is in a different project from the two types (each in their own file), but I've temporarily made *everything* public. I've dropped a breakpoint in and have examined all I can examine, and have done the equivalent of `fieldInfos[1].GetValue(null)` in a Watch expression and it does in fact return null, despite the fact that there is a line in my main class exactly like the second one from `MainType` above.

What is wrong? How do I get all the values of the subtype fields? How is it even possible for them to return null without an error?

On the theory that perhaps for some reason the subtype's class was not being statically constructed due to the access through reflection, I tried

```
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers
  .RunClassConstructor(typeof(SubType).TypeHandle);
```

at the top before starting, but it didn't help (where `SubType` is the actual subtype class in my project).

I'll keep plugging away at trying to reproduce this in a simple case, but I'm out of ideas for the moment.

**Additional Information**

After a bunch of fiddling, the code started working. Now it is not working again. I am working on reproducing what triggered the code to start working.

Note: Targeting .Net 4.6.1 using C# 6.0 in Visual Studio 2015.

**Problem Reproduction Available**

You can play with a working (failing) trimmed-down version of my scenario by downloading this [somewhat minimal working example of the problem at github](https://github.com/erikeckhardt/StaticInitializerCircularDependency/tree/master/src/MyNamespace.Project).

Debug the unit tests. When the exception occurs, step until you get to line 20 of GlossaryHelper.cs, and can see the return value of `GetGlossaryMembers` in the `Locals` tab. You can see that indexes 3 through 12 are null.

Comment: @Fredou Tags added.

Comment: @Fredou Yes, sorry, added to end of post.

Comment: @Fredou I just upgraded to 4.6.1 in my stripped-down project where I'm trying to produce a minimum repro of the problem.

Comment: and last question, 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: @Fredou Platform target is "Any CPU', it's a 64-bit verison of Windows, not sure what type of EXE is being produced, though.

Comment: let us know when you can reproduce it (debug? release? optimize code? any other specific setting?) on my side i tried a few thing and so far i never saw a null

Comment: @Fredou No other special settings. Debug. All other standard settings on a project.

Comment: @ErikE If you can, upload that solution that you have mentioned of 12 files to github so we can download it and try to help you.

Comment: You are running VS with elevated privileges? Try to run VS with privileges and without them to see if both cases give you the same result.

Comment: @camaron Will do when I get back home. Yes on running as administrator already.

Comment: You are describing the behavior of a program with a threading race bug.  That's a real concern with type initializers, the CLR only makes a best-effort to provide the required locking but it will give up without a squeak if it detects a possible deadlock.  In which case it allows the thread to race so getting null because the type initializer for SubType did not complete yet is a real hazard.  The only thing that's not obvious at all from the question is how two threads could possibly be trying to run this code, especially in the unit test scenario.  Embellish please.

Comment: @Fredou github link added.

Comment: @camaron github link added.

Comment: @HansPassant github link added.

Comment: Whoa how could `MainType` initialize a variable using its derived class' member? Can a base class know its derived class if the derived class is defined after base class?

Comment: @MarsonMao That's a puzzle for you to solve, isn't it, since the code was working fine until I tried to unit test it. Hint: don't confuse definition with initialization.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Problem**

The issue has nothing to do with Reflection but instead the circular dependency between the two static field initializers and the order of their execution.

Consider the following snippet:

```
var b = MainType.Two;
var a = SubType.Two;
Debug.Assert(a == b); // Success
```

Now let's exchange the first two lines:

```
var a = SubType.Two;
var b = MainType.Two;
Debug.Assert(a == b); // Fail! b == null
```

So what's going on here? Let's see:

1. Code tries to access `SubType.Two` static field for the first time.
2. The static initializer fires and executes the constructor of `SubType`.
3. Since `SubType` inherits from `MainType`, the `MainType` constructor also executes and triggers `MainType` static initialization.
4. The `MainType.Two` field static initializer is trying to access `SubType.Two`. Since static initializers are executed just once, and the one for `SubType.Two` is already executed (well, not really, it's currently executing, but is considered to be), it simply returns the current field value (`null` at that moment) which then is stored in `MainType.Two` and will be returned by further access requests for the field.

In short, the correct working of such design really depends on the order of the external access to the fields, so it's not surprising that it sometimes works, sometimes not. Unfortunately this is something you cannot control.

**How to fix**

If possible, avoid such static field dependencies. Use static readonly **properties** instead. They give you full control and also allows you to eliminate the field duplication (currently you have 2 different fields that hold one and the same value).

Here is the equivalent design without such issues (using C#6.0):

```
public class MainType
{
    public static MainType One { get; } = new MainType();
    public static MainType Two => SubType.Two;
}

public sealed class SubType : MainType
{
    public new static SubType Two { get; } = new SubType();
}
```

Of course this will require changing your reflection code to use `GetProperties` instead of `GetFields`, but I think it's worth it.

**Update:** Another way to resolve the issue is to move the static fields to a nested abstract container classes:

```
public class MainType
{
    public abstract class Fields
    {
        public static readonly MainType One = new MainType();
        public static readonly MainType Two = SubType.Fields.Two;
    }
}

public sealed class SubType : MainType
{
    public new abstract class Fields : MainType.Fields
    {
        public new static readonly SubType Two = new SubType();
    }
}
```

Now both tests complete successfully:

```
var a = SubType.Fields.Two;
var b = MainType.Fields.Two;
Debug.Assert(a == b); // Success
```

and

```
var b = MainType.Fields.Two;
var a = SubType.Fields.Two;
Debug.Assert(a == b); // Success
```

This is because the container classes, except of being contained in, have no relation to the static field types, hence their static initialization is independent. Also, although they use inheritance, they never get instantiated (because of being `abstract`), thus have no side effects caused by the base constructor calls.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This definitely seems like a useful answer. I have added a github link to the question so you can play with the actual scenario.

Comment: I am certain that I'll be awarding you most/much of the bounty if not all; I am just waiting to see if anyone else has additional information (such as a non-hokey way to continue using fields) and perhaps some more general guidelines and context (computer science theory?) to help me avoid such pitfalls in the future.

Comment: Statics initialization is tough thing. Jon Skeet has a [topic](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx) in his book, I'm pretty sure there are other sources you can find. But in general it's not reliable and you can't control that from the classes, which breaks the encapsulation. If you can force the users of your code to always call first a method that forces `MainType` static initialization (at app startup or something), then you could continue using fields, or if the fields have no cross dependencies etc., But since creating a static readonly property now ...

Comment: ... is so easy - basically the same amount of code, they really should be the first choice. Btw, thanks for editing the answer! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. The problem was I implemented static field of a class and via reflection tried to use the value of it. It worked excellent in my Debug solution but not worked in my production environment.
The problem is compiler in Release configuration found that this static method is never used and remove unreachable code.
To solve this you should remove Optimize code flag.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not it. This is failing in Debug mode, and the Optimize flag is not set.